# C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, visual-studio-code

Project "G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|x64".
Project "G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (1) is building "G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\
node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
Project "G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (2) is building "G:\user\ionic\me\
node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error
 MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK vers
ion in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [G:\user\ionic
\me\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED
.

Done Building Project "G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (default targets) -- F
AILED.

Done Building Project "G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(Desktop_PlatformPrepareForBuild target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): err
or MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK ve
rsion in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [G:\user\ion
ic\me\node_modules\node-sass\build\src\libsass.vcxproj]

```
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.48
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd G:\user\ionic\me\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v10.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.2.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic/app-scripts@1.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/tsc-wrapped@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-08-01T07_15_34_679Z-debug.log

I was facing this error on MSBuild.exe with window 10. 
I tried by installing npm install -g windows-build-tools but got repeated failure. 
But now i run npm install --production windows-build-tools in local folder its working.